# VSCode: Is there an option to generate a function that doesn't exist yet, for Typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I would like to be able to call a function name that doesn't exist yet, and then be able to use quick actions to have it generate a function with that name.  For example, using TypeScript if I type:

```
const name: string = 'Jon'
display(name)
```

I will get an error on `display(name)` that says `Cannot find name: display` because it doesn't exist yet.

What I want is a quick action to auto generate this function so it will write for me:

```
function display(name: string) {
  //TODO
}
```

Is there a plugin for this or anything?  I'm relatively new to VSCode. I'm coming from android development, and Android Studio has this feature which saves me a lot of time.

Comment: I'm not going to tell you that you don't want something, but that's a bug waiting to happen: I guarantee at some point you *will* forget to add a function body to one of those autogenerated functions and it will sneak through to production.

Comment: @Jared Smith can you elaborate?  In Android Studio it makes sure you specify the input type and return type before it will complete.  I use this all the time and I love it

Comment: In the example you posted, it inferred the argument type from use, and you don't assign it to anything, so it would infer return type void, and if you actually expected a side effect from calling it then you will be disappointed when your code compiles but it doesn't happen....as for android studio, Java doesn't have type inference, so it can do that and know the code won't compile until you add the return type.

Comment: @JaredSmith interesting.  I didn't realize I could assign a variable to the result of a function that returns `void` in Typescript.  For the first issue about forgetting to implement it, Android Studio actually calls a `TODO()` function which throws an exception instead of just inserting a comment, which helps you not to forget.

Comment: You can't assign to a variable with the result of a void function, but if you never assign the return to a var then Typescript can and will infer a return type of void, you don't need to annotate it. As for the TODO that throws, well, you'd *hope* that would show up in your tests. But I'm pretty sketchy about turning stuff that could and should be caught at compile-time into runtime errors. If that's a poorly-tested and/or seldom hit code path then it's a time bomb. Static typing has a fairly high cost of adoption, and I want some ROI personally.